# Date issue on PHP

Tags: php, centos

We have a shopping system and getting some orders with correct date but some of them are shown as 1970. We are using below code:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tabloAdi (tarih) VALUES(:tarih)");
$statement->execute([ ":tarih" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("now"))]);
```

Database is MySQL
Table engine is InnoDB
tarih column is datatime

Our server Centos 6.7.

What would be problem of these incorrect dates?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the structure of your table tabloAdi?

Comment: `date()` uses current date/time you don't need `strtotime("now")`.

Comment: and `strtotime('now')` is functionally identical to `time()` anyways, so it's doubly-useless.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Formatting

The format of the `DATETIME` column in SQL is:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:nn:ss[.mmmmmmm]
```

Therefore, `Y-m-d H : i : s` is incorrect as a format. To compare:

```
//your code output
2016-02-12 11 : 16 : 55

//required formatting
2016-02-12EST11:16:55
```

Change this:

```
date("Y-m-d H : i : s", strtotime("now"))
```

To this:

```
date("Y-m-dTH:i:s", strtotime("now"))
```

---

### 2. Placeholder

The placeholder is `:tarih` NOT `tarih` (note the colon), so you should ensure that the key for the placeholder is correct. Change:

```
$statement->execute([ "tarih" //...
```

To:

```
$statement->execute([ ":tarih" //...
```

---

### 3. `date()`

This is not incorrect but useful: `date()` takes the current time *by default*, so you don't need to specify `strtotime("now")`. Therefore you can change:

```
date("Y-m-dTH:i:s", strtotime("now"))
```

To:

```
date("Y-m-dTH:i:s");
```

---

### Full correction

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tabloAdi (tarih) VALUES(:tarih)");
$statement->execute([ ":tarih" => date("Y-m-dTH:i:s")]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`tarih` should be `:tarih`, like this

```
$statement->execute([ ":tarih" => date("Y-m-d H : i : s", strtotime("now"))]);
```